# Encoding korean for crawlling with got

Tags: javascript, encoding, web-crawler, domcrawler

I am trying to crawl a web site with [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) library.

I write a simple code.

```
import got from 'got';

async function test(){
  const data = await got('https://dhlottery.co.kr/store.do?method=topStore&pageGubun=L645', { encoding: 'utf8'});
  console.log(data.body);

}
test();
```

it works, but it doesn't show Korean words properly.

some part of the output is here.

```
<div class="foot_txt2">
  <p>Copyright (c) 2018 ��������ȸ&amp;���ູ��. All rights reserved</p>
  <p>�� Ȩ�������� �Խõ� �̸��� �ּҰ� �ڵ� �����Ǵ� ���� �ź��ϸ�, �̸� ���ݽ� ������Ÿ����� ���� ó������ �����Ͽ� �ֽñ� �ٶ��ϴ�.</p>
  <p class="f_blue2">û�ҳ��� ������ �����ϰų� ��÷���� ������ �� �����ϴ�.</p>
</div>
```

All crashed words are Korean.

I just want to know why this happens, and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this package before or tested the below, but hopefully this might solve your issue.

In your example your defining `utf8` encoding, however, the website uses `EUC-KR` encoding...

[image: page encoding]

So if you update the `encoding` property on your request, that might fix the problem.

```js
import got from 'got';

async function test(){
  const url = 'https://dhlottery.co.kr/store.do?method=topStore&pageGubun=L645';

  const data = await got(url, {
    encoding: 'EUC-KR'
  });

  console.log(data.body);

}
test();
```

Comment: I've found that encoded `euc-kr`, but `got` doesn't support encoding type `EUC-KR`.